# program in which there is high iterations loops in C doesn't give me an output .. why?

Tags: c, loops

I made a program which print the sum of prime numbers which is below 4 million, it doesn't give me an output. When I count prime numbers below 1000 for instance it works well. So what's the problem with high iterations? Here is the function calculating the sum of the primes under a certain number.

```
long long is_prime(){

long long i,j,c=0,sum=0;

for(i=2;i<=4000000;i++){

    c=0;

    for(j=1;j<i;j++){

         if(i%j==0) c++;

    }

    if(c==1) sum+=i ;
}

return sum;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe integer overflows. Try declaring all the ints as long

Comment: `sum` is not enough in a 32 bit int.

Comment: I even tried long long .. the same problem

Comment: It's just taking a very long time. Instead of jumping directly from 1K to 4M, try 10K and 100K, and you'll see that the running time is increasing rapidly.

Comment: How long does it take for the program to actually finish running?

Comment: I tried 100,000 now .. it takes 2 minutes to give me an output

Comment: now I will try 4 million .. let's see if it give me an output :)

Comment: The time-complexity of this code is O(n^2), so it increases as the square of the upper limit. Adding the primes below 1000 may work all right, but adding the primes below 4,000,000 will take *sixteen million times longer.*

Comment: If 100,000 took 2 minutes, 4,000,000 should take a little over two days.

Comment: Build a sieve, find your primes, save them, and be done. A 4-million element sieve on something as remedial as a basic [**Sieve of Eratosthenes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) will take *seconds* to populate, not minutes, hours, or days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense 'doesn't give me output', whether it produces error or it just executing for long time.

Your code's complexity is in O(n*n) that will take time for 4 million* 4 million iterations in worst case, this could be reason, wait for result.